# XSLT 1.0 group by year and add the not existing year

Tags: xslt

I have xml as below(**using xslt 1.0**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <receives>
    <receive>
    <Year>2013</Year>
    <money>120</money>
    </receive>
    <receive>
    <Year>2013</Year>
    <money>150</money>
    </receive>
    <receive>
    <Year>2014</Year>
    <money>130</money>
    </receive>
    <receive>
    <Year>2011</Year>
    <money>120</money>
        </receive>
</receives>
```

I want to group-by the money by year, if the year is not in the list(as above xml, there is no 2011), I need to put 2012 in the result with totalamount=0 as following:

```
<year>2011</year>
<totalamount>120</totalamount>
<year>2012</year>
<totalamount>0</totalamount>
<year>2013</year>
<totalamount>270</totalamount>
<year>2014</year>
<totalamount>130</totalamount>
```

Cureently, I have finished the xslt as following:

```
<xsl:key name="receive-key" match="receive" use="Year" />

<xsl:template match="/receives">
    <xsl:for-each
        select="receive[generate-id() = generate-id(key('receive-key', Year))]">
            <xsl:sort select="../receive[Year = current()/Year]/Year"></xsl:sort>
            <year>
                <xsl:value-of select="../receive[Year = current()/Year]/Year" />
            </year>
            <totalamount>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(../receive[Year = current()/Year]/money)" />
            </totalamount>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This can only group the money by the existing year:

```
<year>2011</year>
<totalamount>120</totalamount> 
<year>2013</year>
<totalamount>270</totalamount>
<year>2014</year>
<totalamount>130</totalamount>
```

Any idea about how to insert

```
<year>2012</year>
<totalamount>0</totalamount>
```

into the result?

Many thanks!

Comment: are the years reasonably limited or can you have a year range from 1900 till 2030?

Comment: What shoukd happen if two years are missing? ie 2011 and 2012?

Comment: @rene all the missed years should be filled by 0. In other word, I would like to show all the years between the min year and max year in the given xml. if there is no value, filled by 0 otherwise, group-by the values by year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this could be with a named template, which is called with a parameter of a year. If this year does not exist in the key, output an empty value, and call it for the next year.

```
<xsl:template name="Year">
   <xsl:param name="Year"/>
   <xsl:if test="not(key('receive-key', $Year))">
      <year>
         <xsl:value-of select="$Year"/>
      </year>
      <totalamount>0</totalamount>
      <xsl:call-template name="Year">
         <xsl:with-param name="Year" select="$Year + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

So, as soon as it finds a year in the key, it will stop outputting the missing years.

One other thing to note, is one of the expressions in your XSLT

```
<xsl:value-of select="../receive[Year = current()/Year]/Year" />
```

This can actually be simplified to just this!

```
<xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
```

Similarly, you can change your sum to make use of the **xsl:key** for efficiency

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('receive-key', Year)/money)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="receive-key" match="receive" use="Year"/>

   <xsl:template match="/receives">
      <xsl:for-each select="receive[generate-id() = generate-id(key('receive-key', Year))]">
         <xsl:sort select="Year"/>
         <year>
            <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
         </year>
         <totalamount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('receive-key', Year)/money)"/>
         </totalamount>
         <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:call-template name="Year">
               <xsl:with-param name="Year" select="number(Year) + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="Year">
      <xsl:param name="Year"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(key('receive-key', $Year))">
         <year>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Year"/>
         </year>
         <totalamount>0</totalamount>
         <xsl:call-template name="Year">
            <xsl:with-param name="Year" select="$Year + 1"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<year>2011</year>
<totalamount>120</totalamount>
<year>2012</year>
<totalamount>0</totalamount>
<year>2013</year>
<totalamount>270</totalamount>
<year>2014</year>
<totalamount>130</totalamount>
```